# При первом, а также последующих нажатиях на кнопку появляться задний фон, как от него избавиться WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо убрать фон при нажатии на кнопку, такая же проблема была и с наведением курсора, однако этот момент я решил с помощью события. Фото при нажатии на кнопку ниже. Как решить этот вопрос. Необходимо чтобы задний фон не отрисовывался.

```
private void forAllButtons_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            b.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
```

[image: здесь]

Comment: Опять я туплю, сори за невнимательность ): Для клика, все же придется её переписывать.

Comment: Вы не используете функционал кнопки: нажатое и отжатое состояние, подсветка фокуса и пр. Поэтому вместо кнопки возьмите компонент, у которого есть события клика и возможность установить картинку. Для этого вполне подойдёт `Panel`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, отличная идея! В прошлом вопросе автора я как раз говорил о подобном:)